# Creating Textfiles within executable JAR

Tags: java, csv, executable-jar

I have created a java application which runs fine, and I have exported it as a jar. The jar export also runs properly, except for one issue:

when I run it e.g. on the desktop, it creates csv files on the desktop.

Is there a way to create csv files and using them at once within JAR without creating them in the background e.g. on the desktop.

I've created my csv files as follows

```
FileWriter training = new FileWriter("TrainingsdatenStatischDynamisch.csv");
```

Thx for any help!!!

Comment: If the file is temporary File then you can delete the file once it is done. `file.deleteOnExit();` will delete the temp file when jvm is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to create csv files and using them at once within JAR
>   without creating them in the background e.g. on the desktop.

You cannot create files within jar, so they have to go somewhere.

The way you open a file it will go to your local directory, which in a gui system is probably your desktop.

You can open the file specifying a better pathname, such as /tmp/filename or similar (note that is a linux pathname).

You might also be able to solve the problem by changing the applications launch settings to set the working directory to your home directory or other location.

Not sure what operating system  or gui you are using though.